# Am I using Cron / Crontab Correctly in Pop_OS! / Ubuntu?

Tags: cron, pop-os, wallpaper

I'm attempting to use dwall (Dynamic Wallpaper) with cron to schedule an hourly wallpaper change on Pop!_OS 21.04, but for whatever reason cron.service isn't executing my crontab file (comment lines excluded):

```
0 * * * * env PATH=/home/m/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin DISPLAY=:1 DESKTOP_SESSION=pop DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus" /usr/bin/dwall -p -s beach
```

When I check to see if cron.service is running (`systemctl status cron.service`), this is the output I get:

```
cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-11-27 17:34:26 EST; 3h 6min ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 980 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38305)
     Memory: 17.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             └─980 /usr/sbin/cron -f -P
```

I confirmed that dwall is working as expected via terminal using either `/usr/bin/dwall -p -s beach` or `dwall -p -s beach`

Comment: Are you sure that `DISPLAY=:1` ? It is often `DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: @sudodus That's what I've seen as well, however the output of ```echo $DISPLAY``` for me is :1. I believe it's because it's detecting (or remembering?) my second TV monitor which is also hooked up to one of my video card's HDMI output port. 

Changing it to :0 had no effect. I suspect maybe the crontab entry is too long, based on the following 2 lines in my /urs/bin/crontab file:

```%s: error while writing new crontab to %s
%s: editor or filename too long
```

These lines occur write when cron should be executing my crontab file. I'll experiment with this further.

Comment: I suggest that you test something simpler, that is still involving a GUI application, and when it works, you can continue to the task that you want to run. The following works for me (you need to have `xterm` installed), `env LANG=C DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xterm -fa default -fs 80 -geometry 6x1 -e bash -c 'sleep 2;echo -n "BANG!";sleep 2'`; You may need full path also for bash and sleep: `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sleep` (check the location of the programs).